# cert-manager Crash Loop

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I used the helm chart to install cert-manager: https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/

For whatever reason, after installing the chart, as well as a third party webhook resolver (for DNS01: https://github.com/vadimkim/cert-manager-webhook-hetzner) I keep getting a crash loop on the cert-manager pods as shown in the image.
[image]

Errors typically take the form of Back-off restarting failed container cert-manager-controller in pod cert-manager and nothing helpful is gained from checking the logs.#

Kubernetes v1.26.5
Helm v3.12.0

ClusterIssuer:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: certs@<mydomain>.co.uk
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-production
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          webhook:
            groupName: acme.<mydomain>.co.uk.tld
            solverName: hetzner
            config:
              secretName: hetzner-secret
              zoneName: <mydomain>.co.uk
              apiUrl: https://dns.hetzner.com/api/v1
```

If any extra details are needed please ask.

-- Update --
Events added here: https://pastebin.com/2CR3n1ew

Comment: kubectl get events --output json,output.

Comment: From the cert manager namespace or default @MikiBelavista

Comment: cert manager namespace .

Comment: Added to the main post, too many lines for S/O

Answer (score 0):

You have to install CustomResourceDefinition resources separately

```
kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.11.1/cert-manager.crds.yaml
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterissuers.cert-manager.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/challenges.acme.cert-manager.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/certificaterequests.cert-manager.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/issuers.cert-manager.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/certificates.cert-manager.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/orders.acme.cert-manager.io created
```

After that repeat the Helm chart install.

Comment: I can confirm I already have these 
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.12.0 \
  --set installCRDs=true